# Window Focus problem with .NET 4.0 and WindowsFormstHost

Tags: wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I'm getting some strange behavior that I'm having trouble with:

1. Add a simple Forms control with
   text box to a WindowsFormsHost;
2. Add a button that opens another
   WPF Window (not setting owner);
3. Maximize the original WPF window
   and click on the text box so it has
   focus;
4. When you do that and then try to
   activate the other WPF window from
   the task bar it gets activated and
   then deactivated.

What is troubling is that if I compile this under .NET 3.5 it works no problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have seen the same problem - have you come closer to a fix?

Comment: This is definitely a bug: 1. This also happens if the window is not maximized 2. It happens if you use ALT+TAB as well! However, if you use WINDOWS+TAB (or Aero switching), it switches to the child window. I don't have time today, but I suspect if there is a way to catch the windows event which occurs when taskbar/alt+tab switching is performed, then the focus can be taken away from the WinfowsFormsHost control, kept in a static field on the WPF application, then reinstated on the switch back to the offending window. I verified that with a regular WPF textbox, this problem does not occur.

Comment: Note: When I say this is definitely a bug, it is not verified with Microsoft.. just the behavior and the symptoms all point to "bug".

Comment: This seems to be some bug. You could submit it to http://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: I tried to output some debug info when the windows got activated/deactivated - the pattern was that the window you want to switch to actually gets activated but then deactivated right away. I also found that using a global shortcut key or clicking on the window works. I'll try to move focus on deactivate and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing this on a derived window helps a bit - but does not solve the problem completely:

```
protected override void OnDeactivated(EventArgs e)
{
  var host = System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost;
  if (host !=null )
  {
    Focus();
  }

  base.OnDeactivated(e);
}
```

It sets focus to the window on deactivate - this is not early enough so activation flips back, but when you alt-tab second time it switches. Focused control is not preserved though. I tried dispatching focus set - but no good.